# Choosing a File Path as Part of a HTML form

Tags: html, forms, file, path

I'm developing an intranet site for my company, and part of the task it has to perform is to hold a database of files and their locations as submitted by users (the files are on a network drive and people viewing the database can click links to the files to access them). I have it working now using a standard text input field where the user enters the path to the file, but is there a way of giving the user a Browse... button to choose the path instead?

Using the type="file" option isn't suitable as I don't want the actual file submitted, and it only gives the filename, not the path for security reasons. But that's the sort of thing I'd like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Browsers aren't designed to expose details of the client file system to the server.

Build your file browser server side instead. The server should be able to access the same network drive.

Comment: Yeah, suspected that... Oh well. Good point about the server-side browser though, it can indeed access the same drive. Thanks!